# What is the difference between one way and two way SSL in client side

Tags: java, ssl, client-server

I am developing a java client with SSL. They are asking me to do one way SSL. Is one way way SSL to be implemented from client side or only from server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in one way SSL , the client verifies the server certificate, but not vice versa. In two way SSL  client verifies the server certificate and the server verifies the client certificate.